# Why does CloudFoundry-uaa save password in DB when using LDAP as authentication source?

Tags: cloudfoundry-uaa

UAA currently seems to save passwords for all users  in the users table in the CloudFoundry's UAA db schema, whether it is authenticated within UAA or by an external identity provider such as LDAP.

Is there a way to disable passwords being saved for users when they are authenticated via LDAP (origin = LDAP).

My current setup is using cloudfoundy-uaa version 2.7.1 and the datastore as PostgresSQL.

The LDAP configuration in uaa.yaml is

```
ldap:
  profile:
    file: ldap/ldap-search-and-bind.xml
  base:
    url: 'ldap://dev.local:389/'
    mailAttributeName: mail
    userDn: 'cn=manager,ou=admin,dc=company,dc=com'
    password: 'password'
    searchBase: 'ou=people,dc=company,dc=com'
    searchFilter: 'cn={0}'
  groups:
    file: ldap/ldap-groups-map-to-scopes.xml
    searchBase: 'ou=groups,dc=company,dc=com'
    searchSubtree: true
    groupSearchFilter: 'member={0}'
    maxSearchDepth: 10
    autoAdd: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Passwords are not saved/managed when using LDAP or SAML as the user stores.  We delegate over the Authentication & User Management entirely to the external user store.

Comment: However, when I login to UAA with an LDAP account and if that user does not exist in UAA yet, it is populating the Users table with username and password along with email, external_Id and origin = LDAP.  Is that password field populated with a default value then ?  Here is a sample - "e031c9cc-ed93-4c07-ac0b-8854997c54d9";"2015-12-30 07:56:47.235";"2015-12-30 07:56:47.235";0;"hyadalam";"$2a$10$.NF558BLXDX10znxWpS8e./H28TffmJmffiMBeaq9bhl/WJKz8gCi";"hyadalam@email.com";0;"hyadalam";"hyadalam";TRUE;"";"uaa.user";TRUE;"ldap";"cn=hyadalam,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com";"uaa";"";"2015-12-30 07:56:47"

Comment: I copied the question over to https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/issues to make it easier for you to respond

Answer (score 0):

It simply appears as there is a password stored in the DB.
When you look at it, it is just an empty string `""` that is stored, but never used.